# Backbone.js route methods not getting called

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've searched various other similar StackOverflow questions but none of them seemed to offer a solution.  I have the following backbone router setup:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
routes: {
    ""           : "homeAction",
    "/portfolio" : "portfolioAction",
    "/about_us"  : "aboutUsAction",
    "/contact"   : "contactAction"
},
initialize: function  () {

},
homeAction: function () {
    alert("User has navigated home");
},
portfolioAction : function() {
    alert('user have navigated to portfolio');
},
servicesAction: function () {
    alert("User has navigated to services");
},
aboutUsAction: function () {
    alert("User has navigated to about us");
},
contactAction: function () {
    alert("User has navigated home");
},
requestQuoteAction: function () {
    alert("User has requested to submit a quote");
}
});

var app = new AppRouter();

$(function() {
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

When I navigated to mydomain.com/# The homeAction route gets called as expected.  However if I try navigating to mydomain.com/#/portfolio, nothing happens.  Any idea why this method is not getting called?

Answer (score 1):

Removing the slash at the begining of your route should work.

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
routes: {
    ""           : "homeAction",
    "portfolio" : "portfolioAction",
    "about_us"  : "aboutUsAction",
    "contact"   : "contactAction"
},
...
```

Then try to go to mydomain.com/#portfolio for example.

Comment: I already tried this, and just tried it once more with your recommendation to no avail.